Word table formula with SEQ operators not working properly on one computer but fine on others
I'm trying to resolve an issue for a customer with a document that uses SEQ formula operators.
I've created an invoice document template and the table uses some SEQ formula operators to calculate the invoice total, amongst some other things, but the template doesn't work correctly on my clients machine. When the fields are updated using F9, the dollar symbols are repeated and decimal places are introduced even when these are zero.
To be clear, the template works correctly on my computer. It also works correctly on my client's colleagues computer too.
I'm confused as to what the problem is. We're both using Windows 11 and we're both using the latest version of Microsoft Office 365 but there must be something different between the two installations? Here's some things I've already tried to resolve the problem:

Client was previously on 'Microsoft Office Mondo 2016' which was thought to be the source of the problem but we've now installed a trial of the latest Microsoft Office 365. Before they updated from Mondo, we were getting messages about the contents of the file being unreadable, but these now don't appear.
Verified that 'Protected View' or anything to do with the Trust Centre is blocking the formulas.
Disabled any Add-Ins.
Ran the Word Document in safe mode.
Stripped all formatting from the document to rule out other conflicts
The document was sent to the client via email, I tried sending via WeTransfer instead, incase email was corrupting the file.

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Here's what formula code I'm using in one of the cells. I'm not an expert in these SEQ operators but I built this based off some other formulas I found on StackExchange, basically it multiplies three cells together to create a total for the row, it works relatively so the same code can be used in all total cells and it won't break if other rows above or below are deleted.
${ =({ QUOTE "D{ =1+{ SEQ row \* Arabic } \* Arabic }" }*{ QUOTE “E{ =1+{ SEQ row \c \* Arabic } \* Arabic }" }*{ QUOTE “F{ =1+{ SEQ row \c \* Arabic}\* Arabic }" }) }

Here's a video of what happens, we're using a stripped back version of the template in that example. I've also uploaded an anonymised version of the file to WeTransfer if anyone wants to test the file directly.

This is probably a consequence of having the operating system set up with different currency symbols. I don't know what all the rules involved are, but let's say you are running on Windows and the currency symbol set up on one machine (in Windows Settings) is $. Then (say) $10 will be recognized as a currency value, the currency symbol will be retained when you multiply the three values together, and Word will use a default currency format (more like "0.00" rather than "0"). So you end up with the following result text:
The literal $ sign that's outside the field code, followed by the field code result, which is $280.00. Overall, $$280.00
But on a system where the currency symbol is set up as £ (say), Word will recognize $10 as a number, omit the $, and won't apply currency formatting. So then your result text will be composed of the following:
The literal $ sign that's outside the field code, followed by the result of 4710 = 280. Overall, $280
Word doesn't recognize any arbitrary piece of text as a currency symbol. If for example you had "P10" in column F, Word would treat that as a piece of text and return 0 rather than 10. But it certainly treats $, £ and the Euro symbol in the way I have described.
How to overcome that so it works as expected everywhere? Probably the simplest thing to do would be to put the $ sign in the Column header (e.g. Rate ($) instead of Rate) and omit it from the data cells. Otherwise, I think you would have to use something like
`{ F3 \#0 }` to ensure that "$10" in cell F3 was treated as "10", and then things get more complicated again if you also have to deal with $10.5, $10.55 and so on.

NB, not relevant to the question but I think you could remove all those \* Arabic modifiers (because \* Arabic is the default format) and use
${ =({ QUOTE "D{ =1+{ SEQ row } }" }*{ QUOTE “E{ =1+{ SEQ row \c } }" }*{ QUOTE “F{ =1+{ SEQ row \c } }" }) }

